# How to run commands as root in Connectbot?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, terminal

My phone is rooted CM7 and Superuser.apk has Connectbot in the allowed list.  Titanium backup reports that it has root access, to prove that I actually have root working.  I seem to remember being able to run commands in Connectbot as root in the past.

But now, I go into Connectbot → Local, and try to run a command using `sudo`, and it just says "permission denied".  No pop-up or anything.   Same for the Terminal Emulator app.  How do I run commands as root?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `su` binary works just like it does on Linux; it runs all commands that follow as root until you type `exit` (or terminate the process, etc.). `sudo <command>` essentially does:

```
su
<command>
exit
```

Android doesn't normally include `sudo`, so If you wish to launch commands like you would with `sudo`, the syntax is as follows:

```
su -c "[command_1;command_2;...;command_N]"
```

For example, to get a list of installed packages in "root" mode, you can either do

```
$ su
# pm list packages
# ........ <listing of packages scrolls down> ......
# exit
```

or

```
$ su -c "pm list packages;exit"
```

Comment: Oh. If I use `su` by itself, it works. Connectbot is granted superuser permissions and then I can do stuff as root. Does `sudo` ever work, then?

Comment: Linux also have `su` binary.. so, don't say `su` as android equivalent of `sudo`.

Comment: `sudo` isn't installed on Android by default; sudo was written to give people the ability to access certain commands (via configuration) instead of using `su` to log in as root all the time. `su` is the more important command when you don't have uid 0 at all on your device.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Feel free to correct my answer with proper verbiage.

Comment: For some reason, this is not working for me in CYM11 (inside an app). For `su -c "pm..."` I get `Permission denied`, and the app appears with a `Deny` in the logs. I have another apps with `Allow`, though. No Toast appeared asking for permissions... Any idea?

Comment: wow! I didn't know `-c` was the tricky option to use. I  just kept trying, say, "`su logcat`" and it never worked.